# How to save the Bigquery result as the table from PHP Script?

Tags: google-bigquery

I query the Big Query table from PHP script and get the result. I want to save the result in new resultant table for future need...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `destinationTable` with the call, the results will be written to the table you set.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#asyncqueries

Answer (score 2):

The option @Pentium10 mentioned works, but there is another way to do it, when you already have query results and you want to save them.

All queries in BigQuery generate output tables. If you don't specify your own destination table, the output table will be an automatically generated table that only sticks around for 24 hours. You can, however, copy that temporary table to a new destination table and it will stick around for as long as you like.

To get the destination table, you need to look up the job (if you use the `jobs.query()` api, the job id is in the jobReference field of the response (see [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query)). To look up the job, you can use jobs.get() with that job id, and you'll get back the destination table information (`datasetId` and `tableId`) from the `configuration.query.destinationTable` (the job object is described [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs)).

You can copy that destination table to your own table by using the jobs.insert() call with a `copy` configuration section filled out. Info on copying a table is [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#copyingtable).

Answer (score 2):

Passing parameters to BQ call is tricky.

This should work in more recent cloud library versions:

```
public function runBigQueryJobIntoTable($query, $project, $dataset, $table)
{
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient(['projectId' => $project]);

    $destinationTable = $bigQuery->dataset($dataset)->table($table);
    $queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query)->destinationTable($destinationTable);

    $job = $bigQuery->startQuery($queryJobConfig);
    $queryResults = $job->queryResults();

    while (!$queryResults->isComplete()) {
        sleep(1);
        $queryResults->reload();
    }

    return true;
}
```

For old versions:

```
public function runBigQueryJobIntoTable($query, $project, $dataset, $table)
{
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient(['projectId' => $project]);

    $jobConfig = [
        'destinationTable' => [
            'projectId' => $project,
            'datasetId' => $dataset,
            'tableId' => $table
        ]
    ];

    $job = $bigQuery->runQueryAsJob($query, ['jobConfig' => $jobConfig]);
    $queryResults = $job->queryResults();

    while (!$queryResults->isComplete()) {
        sleep(1);
        $queryResults->reload();
    }

    return true;
}
```